# Child process hangs, even after closing its input

Tags: c, pipe, fork, posix, child-process

Suppose I have this example code (error checking largely omitted for clarity)

```
static void c_way() {
    int pipefd[2], ch;
    FILE *rf, *wf;
    pipe(pipefd);
    switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        /* something went wrong */
        break;
    case 0:
        dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execvp(cat_args[0], cat_args);
        _exit(0);
    }
    rf = fdopen(pipefd[0], "r");
    wf = fdopen(pipefd[1], "w");
    fprintf(wf, "I have %d apples.\n", 5);
    fclose(wf);
    while ((ch = fgetc(rf)) != EOF)
        putchar(ch);
    puts("Done reading.");
    fflush(stdout);
    fclose(rf);
}
```

where `cat_args` is simply `{"cat", "-", NULL}`. For some reason, despite having closed the parent process's write end of the pipe, EOF never seems to be reached in the `fgetc` loop, as if the child process was waiting for more input. Did I forget to close some file descriptors? Even without using file pointers (i.e. raw POSIX reads and writes), it still hangs.

I see some similar answered questions, so this is probably a duplicate.

Comment: There is a lot of such examples. One obviously wrong thing: the child is both read and writer in the pipe, this is probably not what you want.

Comment: But what if I do want the child to be both a reader and a writer? That is, if I wanted to pipe data to a child for processing and then read its output.

Comment: A single process reading and writing into the SAME pipe is a strange thing, don't you think. A pipe is a communication channel, then at least between two processes. One process writes to it, another one reads in it, that the usual way to manage piping. Seems that in your case you need two pipes...

Comment: And more important, only one single process should read from a pipe. If not, first one get the data and the other(s) have nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run this code I see:

```
[notroot]$ ./c_way 
I have 5 apples.
```

and then a hang.

It's a race:  your parent process reads its own just-written data from the pipe (and writes it to stdout) before the child process exec's *cat*.

The child reads nothing — the pipe has been drained by the parent — and thus blocks patiently on stdin awaiting input.  The parent, meanwhile, blocks patiently on the read end of the pipe, awaiting input which will never arrive.

You want two pipes:  one to connect parent to child stdin, and another to connect child stdout to parent.  (See also [*socketpair*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socketpair.html).)

Comment: Oh, so I read from the pipe way too soon, huh. Without going into socketpair yet (it was one solution that was suggested to me before, alongside plain sockets), you mean I'd need two `pipefd`s?

Comment: @MonatheMonad, yes.  In the present design child and parent compete to read from the pipe.  You want parent's output (to child) to travel along a channel that is not the parent's input (from child).  So, two pipes or bi-directional socket fd semantics.